# code is very slow after using async await?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

here am using async await ,but when am sending the request to this its taking more time to post the data,its bacame very slow?

```
user.user_type = 'admin';
  user.hotelCode = hotelCode;
  user.lastName = ''
  user.setPassword(req.body.password);
  const _id = hotelCode;
  const hotelObj = { _id, email, created_by, country, state, city };
  const hotelDb = new Hotel(hotelObj);
  await hotelDb.save();
  const saveUser = await user.save();
  let token = saveUser.generateJwt();
  const tokenDb = new tokenSchema({ _userId: saveUser._id, hotelCode:hotelCode, token: crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex') });
  const tokenSave = await tokenDb.save();
  await User.update({ email: user.email }, { $set: { token: tokenDb.token } }, { strict: false });
  const mailOptions = {
    from: 'xxxx@gmail.com',
    to: saveUser.email,
    subject: 'Account Verification Token',
    html: '<p>Hello,</br>\n\n' + 'Please verify your account by clicking the link: \nhttp:\/\/'
      + req.headers.host + '\/api/account/verify\/' + '?token=' +
      tokenSave.token + '&email=' + saveUser.email + '\n </p>'
  };
  await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
  let restaurant = new Restaurant({ userId: saveUser._id, hotelCode: hotelCode, name: req.body.name.split(/[\s,]+/)[0] + "'s Restaurant" });
  await restaurant.save();
  res.status(200).json({
    "token": token,
    "user": user
  });
```

Comment: do you have benchmark on your latency for the post request...the performance overhead of using async/await is minimal compared to callbacks.

Comment: hi ..
i have written registration api i want to post the data to above function..the data which am posting it is giving late response...its taking more time to get repsonse from this api..

Answer (score 1):

Last two network calls are independent, so you can call them using promise.all, so that the calls goes in parallel,

```
let restaurant = new Restaurant({ userId: saveUser._id, hotelCode: hotelCode, name: req.body.name.split(/[\s,]+/)[0] + "'s Restaurant" });
await Promise.all[transporter.sendMail(mailOptions), restaurant.save()]
```

Comment: thanks ..now it is littble bit faster as compared to old

Comment: Since you are not using any of the response coming sendmail and restaurat.save, so you can remove the await before the promise.all, so that call will be made, and it will not wait till the response comes those network calls, and you send back the response. it depends upon you, how you go forward.

Comment: sure buddy thanks for your valueable faster response..
omg..this respone is really awesome...

Comment: Promise.all[
        hotelDb.save(),//save hotel here
        User.update({ email: user.email }, { $set: { token: tokenSave.token } }, { strict: false }),//update verification token
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions), //sending email verification to the user
        restaurant.save()];

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you are not using a personal SMTP server. (For example, Google or Yahoo) Unfortunately, nodemailer will not finish Promise until it receives a message from the SMTP server that the email has been sent. Usually, it takes 2-4 seconds. You yourself need to decide what you can do about it. You can send data first and then send an email. Or still wait for the final sending of the letter.